# Why this.setModel() behaves differently based on context

Tags: sapui5

I have followed the tutorials and now I am trying to extend that learning into a real app. In my app I use a JSON model. Unlike the tutorials, mine is a real-world app and I have to get user credentials to act as a filter when I load the data model. In the tutorials the model is loaded in component.js. In my app I have to prompt the user for id and password so I have a login fragment that appears modally over the first view in the app. This happens to be a master view, and critically it runs *after* component.js. After validating the user I collect JSON data from the server via Ajax and place it into the default model via this.setData(my_json).

When testing the routing from master to detail view I produced a stubborn bug in that this.getModel() called in the detail view produced an empty model. Huh - I just set the model in the master view and can see the data in the table control - what gives?

I considered a routing issue but confirmed that was not the problem - I can console log the parameters that pass through the router and anyway the detail view appears so routing is ok.

Recap: I use this.setModel() in the master page then this.getModel() in the detail page but the latter is an empty model.

Question: I want the model to be available across the app. The tutorials focus on setting model in component.js but I cannot. What is the correct syntax for setting the *global* model from the master view for example, or any other place that is not the component.js.

I think I need to use the following in the master (last line is significant):

```
var oModel = new JSONModel(); // declare a JSON model
oModel.setData(<json string>);  // load a JSON string fetched from serve etc.
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);  // important - set as the core model
```

I think the source of my confusion is that in the tutorials it seems that models are set in the component via

```
this.setModel(oModel);  // a line in component.js
```

I therefore assume that *this* in component.js context is app-global whilst *this* in a view relates to the view along, which makes sense. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the tutorials `this.setModel(...)` inside the Component.js will set the model on the Component directly. Therefore, the model is visible in all views inside that Component.

When you see `this.getView().setModel(...)` inside a controller you know that the model is only set on that one view (and therefore it's also visible for it's children).

However, if you see something like `this.setModel(...)` inside a controller you should check what happens inside `this.setModel(...)`. It is possible that the model is set on the view, or on the Component, or even somewhere else! Some of the tutorials make use of the so called "BaseController" concept. This is basically a parent controller of other controllers and therefore this approach allows to code some handy APIs that you can easily reuse in the child controllers that extend from this BaseController. For example, have a look at the [BaseController of the Worklist App](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/741ea8ad8af8b2654a20a00fdb25addf590730dc/src/sap.m/test/sap/m/demokit/tutorial/worklist/07/webapp/controller/BaseController.js#L33-L35). There you can see that the `setModel(...)` API is setting the model on the view. That means whenever you call `this.setModel(...)` in your controllers which extend from that BaseController your model is set on the view!

Furthermore, because in a Master-Detail app there is no hierarchy between Master and Details page (parent/child relation) your models on the Master view are not visible on the Detail view.

In your case it seems to be best setting the model on the Component directly. You can do this by calling

```
this.getOwnerComponent().setModel(...);
```

inside any of your controllers. Or just do it directly on the Component.js [like in the Wordlist tutorial](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/741ea8ad8af8b2654a20a00fdb25addf590730dc/src/sap.m/test/sap/m/demokit/tutorial/worklist/07/webapp/Component.js#L29). You can propagate the data to that model later, i.e. at anytime later from within your controllers.

Comment: Thanks Nabi - very clear and something I shall bookmark as likely to need to refer to in the future no doubt. In my efforts before I posed this question I tried to get the model in the detail view via getOwnerComponent().getModel() and I see now that it would have worked had I set the model into the component from the master using  getOwnerComponent().setModel(). So near and yet so far.